# AlfrescoRuntimeException:GetModelsDiff return status is 403 and api/solr/aclchangesets return status:403

Tags: ssl, solr, alfresco

I installed Alfresco on Windows 7 with the executable default install.My installation is Alfresco community version (5.0.d).

I tried to configue SSL link. I changed the file named `generate_keystores.bat` located in `D:\Alfresco\alf_data\keystore`.

It makes me generate my self-signed certificates.

Then I replaced all .keystore and .truststore with my certificates and I also imported certificates into Java's keystore which is named cacerts.

I configured Tomcat server to browse my `/share` only in https.

When I run it all things look prefect, but I cannot search users and site with it.

It seems the indexing has broken and the solr.log output ERROR logs:

```
 2015-10-13 21:11:15,007 ERROR   
 [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] Tracking failed   
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 09132881
 api/solr/aclchangesets return status:403
        at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getAclChangeSets(SOLRAPIClient.java:159)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.checkRepoAndIndexConsistency(AclTracker.java:347)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.trackRepository(AclTracker.java:313)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.doTrack(AclTracker.java:104)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:153)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:47)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)

'2015-10-13 21:11:15,012 ERROR [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] Tracking failed
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 09132882 GetModelsDiff return status is 403
    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1091)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:249)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:207)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.doTrack(ModelTracker.java:167)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:153)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:47)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

Could anybody tell me the reason of this issue?

Comment: What's in the Alfresco logs?

Comment: THe alfresco logs is Just" failed to send email 2@2".It is obvious that it is not a legal email.The log is :
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 09140032 Failed to send email to:2@2

Comment: It looks like your config is not complete or has errors. The solr tracker is not able to authenticate with client cert configured in solr4/*-SpacesStore/conf/solrcore.properties. Check keystore entries and roles configured in tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml. We have our own scripts to generate the config and don't use the installer at all so someone else may give feedback if the shipped skript is working as expected?

Comment: Thanks,Heiko Robert.I have changed user names  when generated my -store.Then I find the script is wrong when it set ssl.repo.client.keystore /truststore.The script should copy -keystore / truststore into alfresco/solr4/-- .etc..   
 After that, the indexing is still wrong. Then my friends find a solve to fix indexing. just brower the link  "https://127.0.0.1:8443/solr4/admin/cores?aciton=FIX".
then,indexing work.

Comment: I am getting the same error, but not able to resolve. I also referred the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431412/solr-is-not-up-when-we-install-alfresco-5-1-and-solr-in-different-tomcat-instanc but does not work for me. My Alfresco repo 5.2.3 is on different server (tomcat) and my solr instance is on different instance (jetty)