# solr is not up when we install alfresco 5.1 and solr in different tomcat instances

Tags: solr4, alfresco-share

I have installed  alfresco & solr in different tomcat instances using below docs url. alfresco share was running file but when i run solr instance and see below error.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/solr4-install-config.html

generated secure keys for Solr communication.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/generate-keys-solr4.html

```
2016-07-18 13:25:30,037  ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [SolrTrackerSche
ler_Worker-14] Tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 06180034 api/solr/aclchangesets
turn status:403
        at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getAclChangeSets(SOLRAPIClie
.java:162)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.checkRepoAndIndexConsistency(A
Tracker.java:335)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.trackRepository(AclTracker.jav
313)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.doTrack(AclTracker.java:104)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.jav
185)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:47)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool
ava:563)
2016-07-18 13:25:30,029  ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [SolrTrackerSche
ler_Worker-6] Tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 06180033 api/solr/aclchangesets
turn status:403
        at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getAclChangeSets(SOLRAPIClie
.java:162)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.checkRepoAndIndexConsistency(A
Tracker.java:335)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.trackRepository(AclTracker.jav
313)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.doTrack(AclTracker.java:104)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.jav
185)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:47)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool
ava:563)
2016-07-18 13:25:30,056  ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [SolrTrackerSche
ler_Worker-11] Tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 06180036 GetModelsDiff return st
us is 403
        at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.
va:1157)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker
ava:249)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.jav
207)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.doTrack(ModelTracker.java:16

        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.jav
185)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:47)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool
ava:563)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which has been solved by changing

> clientAuth="false"

to

> clientAuth="want"

in Tomcat 7 server.xml
(credit goes to https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ACE-4551?focusedCommentId=424920&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-424920)

Comment: problem is solved. but this is not actual issue.our application is in cluster env.so solr instance also you need to deploy alfresco  application.